# Hiding part of a page until a child component is loaded using vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an SPA using Vue with the default layout being some html in the header, followed by an abstract child component  which gets injected into the page.  Each of the children has a loader so that while the page is loading, the user sees the header html, and the loading icon is presented while the child is fetching data from the server and rendering it:

```
<navbar/>
<child id="main-content"/>
```

I now need to add a footer to each page.  However, it doesn't look so good as adding the footer in the parent default layout results in the header being shown, then the loading icon, then the footer which ultimately gets pushed down only after the data is fetched from the server within the child:

```
<navbar/>
<child id="main-content"/>
<footer>
Stuff in my footer that should not be shown until the child component is completely loaded
</footer>
```

Is there a way to hide the footer in the parent component until the child has rendered all of its data?  I'm hoping for a solution that can be implemented once from the parent without having to add $emit to each of the children.

Comment: Please edit your question with the smallest example code set that you have tried that reproduces your issue and your specific challenge with that so that we may best assist you.

Comment: Edited to hopefully clarify both my code and the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Vue 2, you could implement a [global event bus](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus).

> The event bus / publish-subscribe pattern is a way of getting unrelated sections of your application to talk to each other.

Although, this question seems to expose a bigger issue in your application's data management. To my understanding, all data that is dependant should be coming from the same section.  For example, if your `footer` and `child` component have a dependency on another, then the `parent` should fetch the data for the `child` and pass that data in as props. This way you can handle the loading state for your `footer` component.

Comment: The footer in this case isn't a component; it's just a footer html tag.  If I use the global event bus, wouldn't I then have to still add code to each of my child components to emit the information back?  I'm hoping to be able to write code within the parent component (just once)  which can watch for the completed load of the child components.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do what you're asking for. 

If understand correctly, you want the parent to reach into the child component and listen for the event change when the data is loaded, then update the template of the parent.

The only way that the parent can be aware of this event is with the `$emit()` method, which requires changing the child.

There's an image on this [article](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-data-flow-how-it-works-3ff316a7ffcd) that visually shows how data flows in Vue.

Comment: If this isn't possible, could I still use basic javascript to watch for the event somehow?  If so, then I could hide the element until loaded.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. It's bad practice though since Vue uses a virtual DOM, and it can get out of sync if you're tinkering around like this. JS has an API for adding [custom event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) You'd still need to change the child though to fire the custom event when it's loaded.  Another way to do this would be to set an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) that continuously checks for the DOM element, and when it's found you could clear the interval.  Again, bad practice.

Comment: OK...I'll accept your answer above as that answer along with these comments provide potential paths that I can take.

Answer (score 0):

Another additional option to above  is to use Vuex store, that will know the status of the API data. Each component can have access to the store. This will give you freedom from the need to communicate the fetched data status between the components, or to write any script that checks the status.
This looks like a good case Vuex was made for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).